# multiple otlp exporter with System property

Tags: open-telemetry

i am trying to export http logs to two endpoints and the metrics and spans to the frist endpoint only

frist i tried to add otel.exporter.otlp.logs.endpoint=https://endpoint
this results in ommiting the logs from the frist endpoints and just send to the other endpoint

then i tried using the diffrant naming method that can be used in the yaml conf

otel.exporter.otlp/vector.logs.endpoint=http://127.0.0.1:4318
otel.logs.exporter=otlp,otlp/vector

this also didn't work

here is a the whole System property conf

```
-Dotel.exporter.otlp.endpoint=https://uptrace \
-Dotel.exporter.otlp.headers=uptrace-dsn=https:\
-Dotel.resource.attributes=service.name= \
-Dotel.traces.exporter=otlp \
-Dotel.metrics.exporter=otlp \
-Dotel.logs.exporter=otlp,otlp/vector \
-Dotel.exporter.otlp.protocol=http/protobuf \
-Dotel.exporter.otlp.compression=gzip \
-Dotel.exporter.otlp.metrics.temporality.preference=DELTA \
-Dotel.exporter.otlp.metrics.default.histogram.aggregation=BASE2_EXPONENTIAL_BUCKET_HISTOGRAM \
-Dotel.exporter.otlp/vector.logs.endpoint=http://127.0.0.1:4318 \
-Dotel.exporter.otlp/vector.protocol=http/protobuf"
```